# yii2 init ошибка

Tags: yii2, winginx

С начало пробовал на денвере через composer, там не получилось запустить init выдает такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понял, что версия PHP не совпадает к требованием, так как у меня на денвере уже были другие проекты я не стал обновлять и установил winginx там в пакете есть PHP 5.3.* и PHP 5.4.*. Создал проект yii2.loc, выбрал версию PHP 5.4, Затем скопировал Yii2 из денвера в winginx пробую запустить, снова ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я так понимаю это выходит потому что на winginx по умолчанию стоит PHP 5.3 так как когда открываешь localhost/phpinfo.php именно PHP 5.3 показывает. Пробовал сделать PHP 5.4 по умолчанию ничего не получилось. Как решать задачу?

Comment: Использовать какой-нибудь опенсервер вместо денвера.

Comment: @Etki, да openServer установил, заработал, только вот почему то проект без папки vendor создается, не могу понять в чем причина

Comment: `composer install` же

Answer (score 2):

Для работы Yii2 необходима версия PHP не ниже 5.4

[Новые возможности PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.new-features.php):

> Добавлен короткий синтаксис объявления массивов. Например, $a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; или $a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4];.

Так как ваша версия ниже, она не поддерживает объявление массива с синтаксисом вида `$array = []`, что и приводит к данной ошибке.

Проверить текущую версию php можно написав в консоли команду `php -v`

Answer (score 1):

а вообще в yii2 есть скрипт `requirements.php`

Он как раз нужен для таких случаев.
Советую запускать его после установки yii2